# Multiple Concurrent readers without using lock in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have created a sample program below.In this program I expect two things without lock

1. I have to override the ToString() method and this method should support concurrent readers.
2. It should be thread safe

.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Second.App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sampleClass=new SampleClass();
            sampleClass.AddString("Apple");
            sampleClass.AddString("Orange");
            string allStr =  sampleClass.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class SampleClass:SecondClass
    {
        public override void AddString(string text)
        {
            base.AddString(text);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
    }
    public  class SecondClass
    {
        private readonly List<string> _collection = new List<string>();
        public virtual void AddString(string text)
        {
            _collection.Add(text);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            const string delimiter = ",";
            return _collection.Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimiter + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope some good answers..

Comment: In order to get good answers you need to have a good question. And there's no question here!

Comment: What is the purpose of `SampleClass`? It just overrides but calls `SecondClass`?

Comment: Why "without lock"?  There's a ton of misunderstanding behind that requirement. Just use  a regular lock or a ReaderWriter version.

Comment: Implementation is already *thread-safe* and support multiple readers assuming you are not going to add anything while readers are reading. Or.. well.. I am not sure now, because of iteration, but you can change to `for` -> profit.

Comment: I have to override the ToString() method and this method should support concurrent readers.

Comment: can i support concurrent readers without locking the list?

Comment: You can support as many readers as your system can hold, as long as there are no concurrent writers.

Comment: What is this thing you call "thread safe"?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx

Comment: I want the list become thread safe without using lock

Comment: And instead of the aggregate, please use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx

Comment: @JEMI I'm sorry, but the phrase "I want the list become thread safe" is utterly meaningless. You need to define this. And as soon as it has meaning, then doing it "without using lock" is utterly pointless. Read Eric Lippert's articles about the subject for a good start.

Comment: my ultimate point is creating thread safe collections manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize the performance for a single writer and multiple concurrent readers by caching the folded string. Concurrent readers *may* get a stale string, but the assignment will be atomic. You will however need synchronization if you have more than one writer.

```
public  class SecondClass
{
    private readonly List<string> _collection = new List<string>();
    private string _lastFoldedString;
    private const string delimiter = ",";

    public virtual void AddString(string text)
    {
        // You'll need some synchronization type if more than one concurrent writer
        // lock(_collection)
        {
           _collection.Add(text);
           // Or Use String.Join, or just have a running appender
           _lastFoldedString = _collection.Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimiter + j);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _lastFoldedString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do what you need.

> Use ReaderWriterLockSlim to protect a resource that is read by
>   multiple threads and written to by one thread at a time.
>   ReaderWriterLockSlim allows multiple threads to be in read mode,
>   allows one thread to be in write mode with exclusive ownership of the
>   lock, and allows one thread that has read access to be in upgradeable
>   read mode, from which the thread can upgrade to write mode without
>   having to relinquish its read access to the resource.

I'm fairly certain that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` attempts to avoid OS level mutexes (`lock` uses those) by spinning for short locks and promoting to a mutex for longer locks.

Answer (score 0):

There are various collection classes out there that can handle concurrent access, e.g. in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

But they all work inherently with locks. What other way could there be to handle concurrent access?

Comment: "What other way could there be to handle concurrent access?" Well, locks aren't magical. They need to be implemented too. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx. Then never use it. :-)

Comment: Huh? `Interlocked` also inherently uses locks. I don't understand your comment...

Comment: Well, define "locks". The C# `lock` statement is syntactic sugar for calls to the `Monitor` class, which does its magic using the same processor instructions exposed by the Interlocked class. So in a way, locks use the Interlocked operations, not the other way around. For more information,  http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf is a good read.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Anyway, the bottom line is that all variants boil down to the very same mechanisms.